# Opening Mobile Safari from UIWeb View

Tags: ipad, ios, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I know it is an already discussed topic and I tried all the solutions posted here, but with no success. I have a UIWebView which shows local files and I want to open web links (starting with http://) in Safari, not inside the view. 
Here's the code of my "small" app:
**onceViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface onceViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *slampSite;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) UIWebView *slampSite;

@end
```

**onceViewController.m**

```
#import "onceViewController.h"

@implementation onceViewController

@synthesize slampSite;

#define WWW_ROOT    @"files/en"

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"home" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:WWW_ROOT];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [slampSite loadRequest:request];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)slampSite shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
{  
    NSURL *requestURL = [ [ request URL ] retain ];  
    if ( ( [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"http" ]  
          || [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"https" ] )  
        && ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) ) {  
        return ![ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] openURL: [ requestURL autorelease ] ];  
    }  
    [ requestURL release ];
    return YES;  
} 
[omissis]

- (void)dealloc {
    [slampSite release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the webview delegate's `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method.  When navigationType is `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked`, then examine the `request.URL` if necessary, and open it in Safari with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL]`.

Comment: Thank you!!I tried your suggestion but I think something is still missing (something silly, I suppose). I updated the code, maybe you can find what's wrong!

Comment: Solved... I had to modify the xib file with interface builder.